# How to repeat parts of clips n number of time using python

Tags: python, opencv, video, moviepy

Say, I have a video and I have divided it in 7 parts and saved each of these parts separately and its length is 20 seconds.

```
clip1= VideoFileClip("first.mp4")
clip2= VideoFileClip("second.mp4")
clip3= VideoFileClip("third.mp4")
clip5= VideoFileClip("Fourth.mp4")
clip4= VideoFileClip("Fifth.mp4")
clip7= VideoFileClip("sixth.mp4")
clip6= VideoFileClip("seventh.mp4")

final_clip=concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2,clip3,clip4,clip5,clip6,clip7])

final_clip.write_videofile("new1.mp4")
```

Now what I want to do is, I want to create a program to extend this video to a specified time by randomly repeating these clips.

For instance say I want to make this 20 second long clip to 1 hour long by repeating these 7 clips randomly in python. So video generated will be 1 hour long but will contain random arrangement and repetition of these 7 clips.

Can anybody please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I have tried to randomly arrange them and make a video using moviepy

Comment: Are the clips all the same fps and size?

Comment: @Ann no they are all different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign an id to each clip, say 0-6 for simplicity, why not just randomly generate a list containing the clips you'll need to reach 1 hour :

```
import random

# 1 hour is 3600 seconds
total_duration = 3600
clip_duration = 20

# 180 clips are needed to get an hour-long video
num_clips_required = int(total_duration / clip_duration)

# perform random sampling with replacement
list_of_clips = random.choices(range(7), k=num_clips_required)
```

You could use `moviepy` to construct your final clip :

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

# construct some dictionary containing ids as keys, and VideoFileClip objects as values
D = {0:VideoFileClip("path_to_clip_0.mp4"), 
     1:VideoFileClip("path_to_clip_1.mp4"),
     # etc... 
}
```

Then, write the final clip by doing :

```
combined = concatenate_videoclips([D[id] for id in list_of_clips])
combined.write_videofile("combined.mp4")
```

Comment: I suggest you should provide the code for iterating.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Like you generated a list of these number so how should I generate a video using this list can you please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import random
import cv2
import os

videolist = os.listdir("path to video dir")

while True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("path to video dir/{}.webm".format(random.choice(videolist)))
    while cap.isOpened():

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

        if ret:
            cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
        else:
            print("no video")
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```